# could not delete files from dfs as safe mode is on

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am using cloudera's VM to run hadoop. 99% of dfs space is used up. So I need to delete the files, but to delete the files the safe mode needs to be turned off.

I tried to turn off safe mode with the following commands,

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

It said its been turned off, but due to low space it automatically turns it on. And when I tried to delete file, it says since safe mode is on ,you cannot delete the files.

```
SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /user/cloudera/.Trash/Current. Name node is in safe mode. Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE: If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode.. (error 403)
```

To delete files, safe mode needs to be turned off. To turn off safe mode, I need to free up space! So how do I clean up files to give more space?

Answer (score 5):

You can try lowering the threshold for triggering safe mode by temporarily setting the following options to low values:

```
dfs.safemode.threshold.pct
dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct
```

Also, the NameNode might not go back to safe mode immediately after leaving. In my case, I was able to clean up stuff by chaining the `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` and `hdfs dfs -rm` commands together, e.g.

```
sudo su hdfs
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave; hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /path/to/stuff/to/delete
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to know that HDFS simply uses the disk space of the harddrive. So if on a single node system HDFS is fill then the local disk is also full.

Try if you can cleanup files by removing non hdfs files  (for example /var/log/...)